# Position Image Sprite with CSS on a button

Tags: css

I am trying to do something like this image below with CSS to build the buttons and then an image sprite to show the center content of the button.

[image]

Here is a demo of the code I have so far, I am having trouble getting my sprite images to position correctly.  Any help to improve this CSS to look more like my image above would be great.  I think the actual HTML structure could be improved as well?

http://dabblet.com/gist/2212456

HTML

```
<div class="switch-wrapper">
    <div class="switcher left selected">
        <span id="left">...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="switcher right">
        <span id="right">...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* begin button styles */

.switch-wrapper{
    width:400px;
    margin:220px;
}

.switcher {
    background:#507190;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
#left{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: -0px -0px;
}


#right{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: -0px -17px;
}


.left{
    border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
    width: 45px; height: 38px;

}
.right{
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    width: 45px; height: 38px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -6px

}

.switcher:hover,
.selected {
    background: #27394b;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4),
     inset 0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
      inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.switcher::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border: solid 0px #1B1B1B;
    border-radius: 6px;


}
```

Comment: HTML structure improvements: if you want to design buttons, then use a `button` element or other focusable element like `input[type"submit|image|button"]` or maybe a link (err, button or image here I guess). People using keyboard will then be able to use them and assistive technologies like screen readers will understand easily what are their function in the page. Using HTML image in a button (or via @src in input[type="image"]) instead of sprite CSS will allow to display something (the alternative text) when images are disabled (also with High Contrast Mode in Windows) but CSS enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Block & inline method

http://dabblet.com/gist/2213271

1. Absolute method

http://dabblet.com/gist/2213121

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest to my goal so far.  On all the examples I have seen it seems to make the sprite image smaller then the actual image located here http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you mean by "smaller than the actual image". But in the code #left and #right span didn't have any width. Inside those spans there are 3 dots (...). That gives those span a width. But actual sprite images are bigger than that width. If you increase the count from 3 dots to 4 you can clearly visible the images. You have to set the width & height and use any image replacement like - font:0/0 a; or text-indent:-999em;.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have not defined the position absolute in **#left** & **#right** so i controlled the sprite images through absolute positioned.

you can adjust your images through changes in position top,left,bottom,right whatever you need....

Here is your updated css :-

```
.switch-wrapper{
    width:400px;
    margin:220px;
}

.switcher {
    background:#507190;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
#left{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    background-position: 16px -16px;
    height: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
}


#right{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: -0px -17px;
    background-position: 0 -29px;
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
}


.left{
    border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
    width: 45px; height: 38px;

}
.right{
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    width: 45px; height: 38px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -6px

}

.switcher:hover,
.selected {
    background: #27394b;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4),
     inset 0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
      inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.switcher::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border: solid 0px #1B1B1B;
    border-radius: 6px;


}
```

**or see the live demo:-** http://dabblet.com/gist/2213048